# WCF Service cannot see Web.config file

Tags: c#, wcf

A bit of a newbie question as this is my first WCF service: Running in the development environment the service can see the Web.config file.

When it is deployed to IIS on a server it cannot see this file.

The class accessing this file is:

using System.Configuration;

```
namespace DBService
{
public static class clsSettings
{
    public static string DBServer {get; set;}
    public static string DB { get; set; }
    public static string DBUsername { get; set; }
    public static string DBPassword { get; set; }
    public static Boolean VerboseLogging { get; set; }

    public static void LoadSettings()
    {
        string setting;

        try
        {
            clsSettings.DBUsername = "Login";
            clsSettings.DBPassword = "Password";

            setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseServer"];
            if (setting != null) clsSettings.DBServer = setting;

            setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
            if (setting != null) clsSettings.DB = setting;

            setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VerboseLogging"];
            if (setting.ToUpper() == "TRUE") 
            {
                clsSettings.VerboseLogging = true;
            }
            else
            {
                clsSettings.VerboseLogging = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsError.LogError("clsSettings", "LoadSettings", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the Web.config file contains:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <configuration>
>   <appSettings>
>       <add key="DatabaseServer" value="Server1\SQL2012"/>
>       <add key="Database" value="Licensing"/>
>       <add key="VerboseLogging" value="True"/>
>     </appSettings>
>   <system.web>
>   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
>   <httpRuntime/>
>   </system.web>
>   <system.serviceModel>
>     <behaviors>
>       <serviceBehaviors>
>         <behavior>
>           <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
>           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
>           <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before
> deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
>           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
>         </behavior>
>       </serviceBehaviors>
>     </behaviors>
>     <protocolMapping>
>       <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
>     </protocolMapping>
>     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
>   </system.serviceModel>
>   <system.webServer>
>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
>     <!--
>         To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
>         Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
>       -->
>     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
>   </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```

Deployed it creates the structure:

DBService (folder) containg SPService.svc. It also contains a
bin (folder) containing DBService.dll and DBService.pdb

In the above structure, the bin folder is inside the DBService folder :-)

It also creates a DBService.dll.config file in the bin folder. I have copied this to the parent folder, and also copied and renamed it to Web.config and placed this in both folders. I've also tried renaming Web.config to web.config.

I have made the program print the settings to the Event Viewer and can see they aren't populated.

No Matter what I do it still doesn't pick up the settings from the config file. What does the config file need to be called and where should it be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx).

`ConfigurationManager` is for app.config files of Windows apps, `WebConfigurationManager` is for web applications and their web.config.

Use it like this:

```
setting = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseServer"];
```

Comment: Thanks - I've made this change but it is still not loading the settings. Can you see any other changes to make?

Comment: Not really, I created a default WCF application, added your appSettings in it and got the value of `DatabaseServer` right away.

Comment: Sure the web.config on the IIS server contains the data? Maybe by accident you wrote it in the web.debug.config?

Comment: @jamespearce: Any luck already? If you want to I can send you my test project.

Comment: Yes please:jamespearce111"at"yahoo.co.uk. I think I've narrowed it down a bit - the service seems unable to access the web.config file. I've checked it's not read-only and all users have full control over it. I've also tried different application pools. If I try to navigate to the file via a webbrowser on the server it says "The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section." So I'll look into that next.

Comment: One other potential cause: I have not published/transformed web.config or used the web.release.config file. I have just rebuilt the project and copied the above web.config file across. Could this be incorrect?

Comment: The last one seems more like a reason. Did you check the server web.config? Will send sample later since I am not on my laptop now.

Comment: The service is now published to IIS properly and it still isn't working. My colleagues can't see anything else to do and think they may have misconfigured IIS. I'll try the service you sent to test this.

Comment: Thanks for the sample: The config settings in that do not work on the IIS either, so it must be something to do with the Application Pool or other setting. Marked this as the answer as it should work under normal circumstances. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jamespearce: I triple checked it and it does work for me, even after deployment to IIS. Does the setting exist in the web.config on the server?

Comment: I'm soon to set up a second instance of IIS on a different server, so I'll see if the service can access it's config there. I suspect it will and the issue is with our installation of IIS

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the update. Will wait if you need more help.